# Full Text Search Launcher service and process

Tags: sql-server-2012, index-tuning, full-text-search

I am puzzled by the full text search in sql server. I am trying to break down the issue in multiple sub questions, maybe that would help to bring some light into the situation.

0. I created an environment to test full time search in sql server. My play system is 2012, but I have additional systems installed including (2014,) 2016, 1017 and 2019. I test if full text search works like this:

   ```
    drop table dbo.test_full_text_search;
    go

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_full_text_search](
        [id] [int] NOT NULL,
        [name] [varchar](max) NULL

        CONSTRAINT pd_test_full_text_search_id PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )
    GO

    CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON test_full_text_search (name Language 1031) KEY INDEX pd_test_full_text_search_id WITH STOPLIST = SYSTEM;

    truncate table test_full_text_search ;

    insert into test_full_text_search (id, name) values
      (1, '111')
    , (2, '111, 222')
    , (3, '111, 222, 333')
    , (4, '111, 222, 333, 444')
    , (5, '111, 222, 333, 444, 555')
    , (6, '111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666')
    , (7, '111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777')
    , (8, '111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666, 777, 888');


    select * from test_full_text_search where CONTAINS(name, '111');
   ```

The query plan shows that an index is used:

[image: full text index query plan]

1. If the `fdhost` and `fdlaucher` processes are not running, then the select query fails with the error (not surprisingly):

   ```
    0046, Level 16, State 1, Line 37
    SQL Server encountered error 0x80070422 while communicating with full-text filter daemon host (FDHost) process. Make sure that the FDHost process is running. To re-start the FDHost process, run the sp_fulltext_service 'restart_all_fdhosts' command or restart the SQL Server instance.
   ```

The only way to get those processes stopped was to disable the `fdlauncher` service and stop the `fdhost` process.

2. It is not that simple to get `fdhost` and `fdlauncher` switched off. If one stops the `fdhost.exe` process, another one is immediatelly fired up, even if `fdlaucher` service is not running. What windows process starts `fdhost.exe` then, if it was stopped?
3. How does the overall architecture then looks like? I can stop the `fdlauncher` service. But as long as I stop the `fdhost` process, `fdlauncher` service is then started, and `fdhost.exe` is also started as well. does that mean that sql server monitors if `fdlauncher`
4. What happens if there's so much work on the computer `fdhost` cannot keep up with indexing tasks? Does that mean that query

   ```
    select * from test_full_text_search where CONTAINS(name, '111');
   ```

may return incomplete results (retrieve only the instances, that are already indexed, and don't return not yet indexed tuples? Or insert statements would wait until they also get indexed? If that is the case, why create such a complicated architecture then?)

Answers for Q2, Q3 and Q4 were very nice.

Comment: Why do you want to use full text search, but also turn off full text services?

Comment: I am trying to investigate if the solution works, sysadmins turn this off, or if indexing is too slow to update